# How to fix these issues?

Tags: java

I have received four error messages in my code. It states that in modes 2 and 4, dArea cannot be resolved to a variable. Later in the code, the same variable is said to be duplicated even though it has only been assigned value, used, and returned. How can I fix these issues?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab7
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
    // Created by Makayla Scull, period 4B

    String sMode;
    int iMode = 0;
    sMode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menu: \n [Square: Press 1] \n [Rectangle: Press 2] \n [Circle: Press 3] \n [Triangle: Press 4] \n [Trapezoid: Press 5] \n [To Exit: Press 6]");
    iMode = Integer.parseInt(sMode);

    while(iMode == 0);
    {
        if (iMode == 1)
        {
            Geometry.methodSquare();
        }

        if (iMode == 2)
        {
            Geometry.methodRectangle(dArea);
        }

        if (iMode == 3)
        {
            Geometry.methodCircle();
        }

        if (iMode == 4)
        {
            Geometry.methodTriangle(dArea);
        }

        if (iMode == 5)
        {
            Geometry.methodTrapezoid();
        }

        if (iMode == 6)
        {
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class Geometry
{
    public static void methodSquare()
    {
        String sLength;
        double dLength;
        double dArea;
        int exp = 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the square.");
        sLength = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the side length of the square.");
        dLength = Double.parseDouble(sLength);
        dArea = Math.pow(dLength, exp);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the square is " + dArea);
    }

    public static double methodRectangle(double dArea)
    {
        String sLength;
        String sWidth;
        double dLength;
        double dWidth;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the rectangle.");
        sLength = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the rectangle.");
        sWidth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of the rectangle.");
        dLength = Double.parseDouble(sLength);
        dWidth = Double.parseDouble(sWidth);
        double dArea = (dLength * dWidth);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the rectangle is " + dArea);
        return dArea;
    }

    public static double methodCircle()
    {
        String sRadius;
        double dRadius;
        int exp = 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the circle.");
        sRadius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the radius of the circle.");
        dRadius = Double.parseDouble(sRadius);
        double dArea = Math.pow(dRadius, exp) * Math.PI;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the circle is " + dArea);
        return dArea;
    }

    public static double methodTriangle(double dArea)
    {
        String sBase;
        String sHeight;
        double dBase;
        double dHeight;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the triangle.");
        sBase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the base length of the triangle.");
        dBase = Double.parseDouble(sBase);
        sHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height of the triangle.");
        dHeight = Double.parseDouble(sHeight);
        double dArea = (dBase * dHeight) / 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the triangle is " + dArea);
        return dArea;
    }

    public static void methodTrapezoid()
    {
        String sHeight;
        String sBase1;
        String sBase2;
        double dHeight;
        double dBase1;
        double dBase2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the trapezoid.");
        sHeight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height of the trapezoid.");
        dHeight = Double.parseDouble(sHeight);
        sBase1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the first base of the trapezoid.");
        dBase1 = Double.parseDouble(sBase1);
        sBase2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the second base of the trapezoid.");
        dBase2 = Double.parseDouble(sBase2);
        double dArea = ((dBase1 + dBase2) * dHeight) / 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the trapezoid is " + dArea);
    }
}
```

Comment: java != javascript.  `dArea` _is_ undefined in your `main` method - did you mean to pass in a value you'd collected there?  And then in the others you _are_ redefining it when it's passed in as a parameter.  Please re-read the error messages you've got and look in detail at what they're telling you.  It's hard to say how exactly to fix your code, as it depends on what you're intending it to do.

Comment: Another error: `while(iMode == 0);` remove the semicolon. Also, the logic inside your while doesn't make *any* sense. How could `iMode` equal 1, 2, 3, or 4 **while** it is `0`??

Answer (score 2):

> in modes 2 and 4, dArea cannot be resolved to a variable

That's because you never defined that variable.  You try to use it:

```
Geometry.methodRectangle(dArea);
```

But nowhere in that scope have you *defined* it.  A value has to exist before it can be used.

---

> the same variable is said to be duplicated

Your methods define a variable as a parameter to the method:

```
public static double methodRectangle(double dArea)
```

But then also try to declare it again within the method:

```
double dArea = (dLength * dWidth);
```

Just as the error is telling you, a variable can only be declared *once* in any given scope.  If you try to have two variables by the same name in the same scope then the compiler would have no way of knowing which one you're referring to.

Comment: Almost felt bad re-tagging this Q... I'm not active in [Java] and had no idea how well it would go down in this sub-community!

Comment: @JamesThorpe: It's a terrible question, I admit.  And as a result my answer may have some off as a little terse.  But hopefully the OP (and maybe even future visitors) can be somewhat helped.